# Passivation issue with Stateful Session Bean

Tags: java-ee-6, jboss6.x, jboss-weld

I'm using JBoss 6.1 Final, and get the following error message after my web application is running for a while (note the application doesn't crash), followed by a very long stack trace.  I notice that this problem only occurs with stateful session beans that have other stateful session beans injected into them.

> 16:10:59,769 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache.UutSerialNumberServiceBean] problem passivation thread: javax.ejb.EJBException: Could not passivate; failed to save state

Here is the offending stateful session bean...

```
package com.ray.TEI.ejb;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

import com.ray.TEI.model.TestProcedure;
import com.ray.TEI.model.Uut;
import com.ray.TEI.model.UutSerialNumber;

@Stateful
public class UutSerialNumberServiceBean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="jasoni", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
  protected EntityManager em;
  @Inject private ExecProcedureServiceBean execProcedureServiceBean;

  public boolean isDuplicateSerialNumber(Uut uut, String serialNumber) {
    return ((Number)em.createNamedQuery("UutSerialNumber.getCountByUutIdAndSerialNumber")
             .setParameter("uut", uut)
             .setParameter("serialNumber", serialNumber)
             .getSingleResult()).intValue() > 0;
  }

  public UutSerialNumber findUutSerialNumberByUutSerialNumberId(Integer uutSerialNumberId) {
    return em.find(UutSerialNumber.class, uutSerialNumberId);
  }

  public UutSerialNumber editSerialNumber(Integer uutSerialNumberId, String serialNumber) {
    UutSerialNumber uutSerialNumber = findUutSerialNumberByUutSerialNumberId(uutSerialNumberId);
    uutSerialNumber.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
    return uutSerialNumber;
  }

  public UutSerialNumber createSerialNumber(Uut uut, String serialNumber) {
    UutSerialNumber uutSerialNumber = new UutSerialNumber();
    uutSerialNumber.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
    uutSerialNumber.setUut(uut);
    uut.getSerialNumbers().add(uutSerialNumber);
    em.persist(uutSerialNumber);
    for (TestProcedure testProcedure : uut.getTestProcedures()) {
      execProcedureServiceBean.createExecProcedure(uutSerialNumber, testProcedure);
    }
    return uutSerialNumber;
  }
}
```

Here is the injected stateful session bean...

```
package com.ray.TEI.ejb;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;

import com.ray.TEI.model.ExecProcedure;
import com.ray.TEI.model.TestProcedure;
import com.ray.TEI.model.UutSerialNumber;


@Stateful
public class ExecProcedureServiceBean implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @PersistenceContext(unitName="jasoni", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
  protected EntityManager em;

  public ExecProcedure createExecProcedure(UutSerialNumber uutSerialNumber, TestProcedure testProcedure) {
    ExecProcedure execProcedure = new ExecProcedure();
    execProcedure.setUutSerialNumber(uutSerialNumber);
    execProcedure.setTestProcedure(testProcedure);
    execProcedure.setIterationCount(0);
    em.persist(execProcedure);
    return execProcedure;
  }
}
```

anyone know what's wrong with this?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EntityManager` [is not serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html), I guess that's why it fails.

Couple of options from here:

- deactivate passivation (easiest option in case you don't need that mechanism)
- remove persistence-context from SFSB (this will most likely kill your EXTENDED mode)
- replace EntityManager with Hibernate-Session, which *is* serializable (consider that experimental, I've never tried it out myself)

Comment: Thanks Jan.  I tried to deactivate passivation using
"@CacheConfig(maxSize = 0, idleTimeoutSeconds = 0)"
and now have a different problem.  I'm injecting these Stateful Session beans into a RequestScoped backing beans in order to load view data and now, it seems that even though an object is injected (for example, printing out the reference gives
"No-Interface view for endpoint [ jboss.j2ee:jar=TEI.war,name=ProgramServiceBean,service=EJB3 ] and session 43g443f-ep5eqs-h1822776-1-h18233w9-df"
 - but, method calls on the object aren't working.  Any ideas?
Thanks again! Jason

Comment: different problem -> new question... :) That's way easier to handle.