# Java EE, GlassFish restarts suddenly

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee

**I am learning Java EE.**

First I will write about some exceptions I have found and the ways I did to solve them. ***Then I will ask the current exception.***

To implement a way to log each class and method access, I wrote to a local file. First I tried Files.write class, and then I realized it reported an EOFException. The way I solved it was to use the BufferedWriter:

```
private void writeLogToFile(String text, File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter output = null;
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
        output.write(text);
        output.close();
    }
```

Then to implement session persistance, I managed to store the Courses and Assessments being created in the HttpSession of the user. However I saw it reported isNotSerializable exception. To handle this I implemented Serializable in both classes which we persist in session as:

```
public class Evaluacion implements Serializable {
```

To implement a page to see all program's logs I used a Singleton. Then to keep track of all page's statistic as each time an user visits it, we used another SIngleton. The difficulty was that each time GlassFish started, the first Singleton, would use the second one, and could not ind it by JNDI, because it was not deployed yet. So then I used @DependsOn tag.

In addition GlassFish was warning me because it had trouble to passivate Statefull beans, because I had in the method tagged with @PrePassivate a reference to statistics singletons. So then I had to remove the body's content.
Other similar issue: [Passivation issue with Stateful Session Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219685/passivation-issue-with-stateful-session-bean)

**Here comes the current difficulty: Each time I access a statefull, GlassFish restarts suddenly.**

The log I have is:

```
Grave:   The Class frontController.EvaluacionCommand having annotation javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet need to be a derived class of javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.
 symbol: TYPE location: class frontController.EvaluacionCommand

Grave:   The Class frontController.AlumnosCommand having annotation javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet need to be a derived class of javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.
 symbol: TYPE location: class frontController.AlumnosCommand

Grave:   The Class frontController.CuestionarioCommand having annotation javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet need to be a derived class of javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.
 symbol: TYPE location: class frontController.CuestionarioCommand

Grave:   The Class frontController.EncuestaCommand having annotation javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet need to be a derived class of javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.
 symbol: TYPE location: class frontController.EncuestaCommand

Grave:   The Class frontController.CourseInfoCommand having annotation javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet need to be a derived class of javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.
 symbol: TYPE location: class frontController.CourseInfoCommand
```

I have searched and it is because of each class which uses @WebServlet needs to implement HttpServlet.

However I am implementing FrontServlet pattern and I need to extend each command from FrontCommand abstract class.

So then I can not do something like:

```
class AlumnosCommand extends HttpServlet implements FrontCommand
```

***How could we solve this difficulty?***

Thank you for your help.